# Return a one-dimensional map from a nested map in groovy

Tags: java, dictionary, groovy, nested

I would like to get a flattened map from a nested map. The flattened map must have the keys separated by a dot.

For instance,

```
def map = ['environment':'production', 'classes':['nfs-server':['exports':['/srv/share1', '/srv/share3']]], 'parameters':'null']
```

The expected output is

```
[environment:'production', classes.nfs-server.exports:['/srv/share1', '/srv/share3'], parameters:'null']
```

I looked around and came up with the following code snippet that uses recursion. Here is the code

```
def Map<String, String> getNestedMapKeys(Map map, String keyPrefix = '') {
def result = [:]
map.each { key, value ->
  if (value instanceof Map) {
    result += getNestedMapKeys(value, keyPrefix += "$key.")
  } else {
    String finalKey = "$keyPrefix$key"
    // need to wrap in parenthesis because it's a variable
    result << [(finalKey): value]
  }
}
result
```

}

the output from running it is

```
[environment:'production', classes.nfs-server.exports:['/srv/share1', '/srv/share3'], classes.parameters:'null']
```

So the keys processed after a nested map are still retaining the prefix. In this case 'classes.parameters' should be just 'parameters'. Any help fixing it is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Needed to reset the 'keyPrefix' variable at the end of processing a nested map in the main map.

```
def Map<String, String> getNestedMapKeys(Map map, String keyPrefix = '') {
def result = [:]
map.each { key, value ->
  if (value instanceof Map) {
    print 'key prefix is ' + keyPrefix
    result += getNestedMapKeys(value, keyPrefix += "$key.")
    keyPrefix = ''
  } else {
    String finalKey = "$keyPrefix$key"
    // need to wrap in parenthesis because it's a variable
    result << [(finalKey): value]
  }
}
result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
def flattenMap(Map map) {
    map.collectEntries { k, v ->
        v instanceof Map ?
            flattenMap(v).collectEntries { k1, v1 ->
                [ "${k}.${k1}": v1 ]
            }
        :
            [ (k): v ]
    }
}
```